# Use of tokens in Events - Online Registration Intro Text and Confirmation email

Tags: civievent, tokens

We have events over multiple days. The Intro Text on the confirmation screen and the confirmation email only show start date and time and end date and time. Registrants don't see the specific dates and times of multiple day events. In the reminder email we can insert tokens `{event.summary}` and `{event.location}` and it works great to give all the details.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange!  It would be helpful if you could edit your question to include the version of CiviCRM you are using (and also your CMS - WordPress, Joomla or Drupal).  The answers may vary depending on the version you are using.

Comment: Thank you for responding. We are on version 4.7.14, Drupal.

Comment: Did you try {$event.summary}?

Comment: We figured out that  {$event.event_description} worked. Thanks for the reply.